# Cannot able to upload user Profile react native firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to update User profile so I created Profile js file, but Cannot able to retrieve User data because I am not storing user data in database
So how can I update active user account data name, email, photo, password. so below is my register user account code. Should I need to store User data in database?

**Register screen**

```
    const RegisterScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
          const [name, setName] = useState("")
            const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
            const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
            const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
              
            const pickImage = async () => {
        
               // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
                let result = await   ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
                 
                  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
                  allowsEditing: true,
                  aspect: [4, 3],
                  quality: 1,
                });
          
              
                console.log(result);
            
                if (!result.cancelled) {
                  setImage(result.uri);
                  
                  
                }
              
              };
        
     
            useLayoutEffect(()=>{
        
                navigation.setOptions({
                    headerBackTitle:"Back to Login"
        
                });
        
            },[navigation]);
        
            const register = () => {
        
                
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
               
        
                .then((authUser) => {

   db.collection('users').set(doc(user.uid).set({
                displayName: name,
                photoURL: image,
                password: password,
                email: email,
    
            }));
                    authUser.user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: name,
                        photoURL: image
                    })
        
                   
                })
                .catch(error => alert(error.message));
               
            }
        
            return (
        
                
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.container}>
        
                    <ScrollView>
                
                    <StatusBar style="light" />
                    <Text h3 style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}>
                        Create a Signal account
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Full Name"
                            autoFocus
                            type="text"
                            value={name}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
                        />
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Email"
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                        />
                        <Input
                            placeholder="Password"
                            type="password"
                            secureTextEntry
                            value={password}
                            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                        />
        
                      
                    </View>
                    
                    <Button buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#49C958ed',}} 
                        containerStyle={styles.button}
                
                        raised title="Upload Image"   onPress={pickImage} />
                    
                    <Button  buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#49C958ed',}} 
                        containerStyle={styles.button}
                        raised title="Register" 
                        onPress={register} 
                    />
        
        </ScrollView>    
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The four properties you mention (name, email, photo, password) can all be stored in the Firebase Authentication user profile. For name and photo you can use `updateProfile` as you already do, while for email and password you'll use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth).

If you want to store additional properties, or want to use the properties in a way that Firebase Authentication doesn't allow, you'll indeed need to store those in a database, such as Firestore's Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.

Comment: now I stored my user information to firestore but i am afraid may be this well not update info because in firestore Uid is different from user id that present in Authentication. Basically I need to make profile page from their user can change its data name image etc

Comment: "in firestore Uid is different from user id that present in Authentication" That sounds like something you'll want to fix then. Instead of calling `addDoc()` (which generates its own document ID), consider calling `set(doc(collectionRef, user.uid), {...})` so that the UID of the user is used as the  document ID in Firestore.

Comment: got error doc is not define

Comment: db.collection('users').set(doc(user.uid).set({
                displayName: name,
                photoURL: image, 
                password: password,
                email: email,
    
            }));

Comment: I also add this in code please how can I make both auth id and firestore Id same because I need to change info and update it

Comment: That was meant as pseudo-code, so you'll have to spend some time in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) to make it work. Based on that link: `db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({...})`. This will make the database's document ID the same as the UID of your user.

Comment: yes I finally did this but now profile is not updating I add code of profile.js above.

Comment: Frank thank you for firestore issue it fixed finally but now I want to update profile

Comment: I posted new question now I just want to fetch data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570568/want-to-fetch-current-user-photourl-and-name-firestore-react-native

Comment: firestore ID and Auth currrent ID is same so just need to show profile info